# Creating a database table from code with PHP

Tags: library, php, mysql

I have been experimenting with Python Django, and what I really liked was creating a database table from a model created in Python.

I would love to do the same with PHP. I have been plowing through Packagist without any luck. So I started working on something myself. And you guessed it, it became a project on its own now.

Does anyone know any library, preferably on Packagist that does this? Any other suggestions would be welcome. Also, don't hold back on commenting this method in general. However I really believe that this concept is valuable.

Note: I just like the idea of not having manage all kinds of models in MySql workbench for small projects.

Answer (score 1):

```
use mysqli or pdo.

Then you input a standard SQL statement in and execute it.
$db=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','xxxx');
mysqli_select_db($db,'db');
mysqli_query($db,"create table scooby { col1 varchar(300),col2 varchar(10);}");
```

A very simply example with no error checking.

Comment: Thanks. I know mysql. I'm looking more for a model/oop library through which I can manage the tables. Also I would like to update databases without losing the data contained in the database already. Like CTRL+Y in  mysql workbench, let's say.

Comment: Not what you are looking for (I think), but stil very well worth taking a 30 second look at http://www.grocerycrud.com/examples  That should be enough to show its usefulness